# Creating module via web-interface

Tags: odoo

I followed the following steps to create a module named "x_test" :

```
1. Settings -->Technical --> Database Structure --> Models --> Create
Model Description : Test
Model :x_test

2. Add Fields
Name: x_sample
Field Label: sample
Field Type: boolean

3. Save 

4. Click on Create a Menu

5. Select appropriate menu and click on "CREATE MENU"

6. Click on the menu provided and try to provide values for my custom module

7. When I "SAVE" my record, I am getting the following error:
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
File "/var/app/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/var/app/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/var/app/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/var/app/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/app/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/var/app/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/var/app/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4434, in create
    cr.execute('insert into "'+self._table+'" (id'+upd0+") values ("+str(id_new)+upd1+')', tuple(upd2))
  File "/var/app/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 161, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/app/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 228, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: column "x_sample" of relation "x_test" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into "x_test" (id,"x_sample",create_uid,create_date,wri...
```

Is there any mistake in my regards of creating a module via Web Interface

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, go into the database and within the table x_test create the field you added in the model.

Now as far as I am concerned, it should create the fields for you. But I have had to create the fields manually.